# Django admin: Can I search through a field from another data table in search_fields?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-admin

Is it possible to search through a field from different database table using serach_fields in django? Please see the following example for better understanding.

> model.py

```
class test1(models.Model):
    sources = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

class test2(test1):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

> admin.py

```
class test1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['sources']

class test2Admin(test1Admin):
    ...
```

In this case, the search_fields at test2 is not working. I know why it is not working. However, I was wondering if there is any way to search 'sources' field from test2 table?

Comment: Does `test2` have a relationship with `test1`?

Comment: test1 is basically the abstract class. Imagine ten more classes similar to test2 that inherited test1.